# Eclipse basic syntax font change

Tags: eclipse, syntax, ide

I use a company specific plugin to Eclipse IDE, to be able to view and modify our ERP system's script files.
When I change the syntax coloring, it is not affecting the base font color in the code editor.

Question:
Does anyone know which .jar file in Eclipse IDE folder I should modify to change the code's main/basic font color in Eclipse ?

I tried various context of syntax coloring in Eclipse's preferences ... and none of it works.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: It is not possible to say without knowing how your company specific plugin works.

Comment: I am under an NDA so sorry, no-can-do, but is there any file in eclipse which holds the general settings of the colors ?

Comment: There is no single file. It all depends on the workings of the editor.

Comment: Ok, hopefuly I'll get to that  @greg449